# How to get rid of !important tags?

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

This is crazy. I set default rules for example for

```
#page a {
  color: #000;
}
```

And then if I have a new link somewhere deep in the divs inside that #page (which is main wrapper for entire site) which needs different styling and color, it only works with !important. And just like that now almost every new styling rule goes with !important to make it work, colors, font-families, font size and etc.

I use one .css file, how do I get rid of !important tags? All my CSS file is in red from all those !importants. I am asking this because I read somewhere that !important is bad and should be avoided, so how do I do that?

Comment: You need to learn about specificity.

Comment: and to cascade your rules correctly

Comment: So what is that? Learn how?

Comment: You can remove that color from `#page a` and then group all your links by class and then apply the color you want to each class in CSS.

Comment: would be better to share the problem with some Demo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove the initial !important
2. assign a class to like properties so that all h1, h2, ...p, em, a, etc have their individual color
3. if you have two h1 or p or a that need separate styles, use a class or use targeting for example

   ```
   <p class="text1"> A text </p>  
   <div class="txtgroup">
      <p> Another text </p>
   </div>
   ```

you can style these as follows:

```
.text1 {color: #fff}
.txtgroup p{color:#cdcdcd}
```

1. And finally, leave your main css framework untouched. Create a custom.css, add your style modification there and declare it directly under the css that is being overwritten

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for infos. I just learned that I had to replace the ID #page a with .class instead of #id and now all rules work without !important.